# Как покрыть список инициализации define'ом , если не знаешь, сколько будет параметров?

Tags: c++

Используются uniform-инициализации вида:

```
{ 0,{ { 100,{ "занять","занят","занятый","занятый", "занятые","займите","займете","займет" } } } },
```

Из-за большого количества скобок хотел покрыть её дефайном для более приятного вида:

```
#define INIT_SOMETHING(num,w1,w2,w3,w4,w5,w6,w7,w8) {num1,{{num2,{w1,w2,w3,w4,w5,w6,w7,w8}}}},
```

Для конкретно этого примера, естественно, сработает, но если я захочу большее или меньшее количество параметров, то нет. Копипастить дефайн под каждое количество параметров - не хочется, да и тупо это, наверное. Есть ли какой-то способ, который поможет сделать то, что я хочу?

p.s. или использовать дефайн для таких вещей вообще не стоит?

Comment: По-моему, он тут совершенно не нужен. Не ст*о*ит того...

Comment: но если очень сильно хочется, может посмотреть на `__VA_ARGS__`?

Comment: @Harry спасибо, учту.

Comment: @KoVadim благодарю! Это то, что я искал!

Comment: Зачем дефайн? Напишите функцию.